# FBInstant.shareAsync() function doesn't work without any errors in facebook instant game Share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-instant-games

I created a facebook instant game and in the end there's a share button, how to make that share button shares the result or a photo in a link to play the game on the player's profile.
Here's my code of the shareAsync() function, which produces no javaScript errors but yet doesn't work.

```
$(document).on("click", ".share-result", function(){
   FBInstant.shareAsync({
       intent: 'INVITE',
       image: img,
       text: 'Play this Awesome game',
       data: {myReplayData: '...'},
   }).then(function() {
       location.reload();
      });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A base64Image must be passed in the `image` object of FBInstant.shareAsync() function.** In your case, pass onto your `img` var.
For sample working, `img` var below has an image of 1.9 kb in the form of base64 code.

```
var img = "data:image/png;base64,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";
FBInstant.shareAsync({
     intent: 'INVITE',
     image: img, // base64Image code must be passed in img
     text: 'Play this Awesome game',
     data: {myReplayData: '...'},
}).then(function() {
     location.reload();
   });
```

For testing now, use this [site](https://www.base64-image.de/) to upload your image, convert it to base64 and copy the image code that starts with `data:image/` ending in a very long hash.
**Store the copied code into your variable named** `img`. It must work then.

Comment: Yeah it worked, that was great :D
Thanks a lot
it's hard to find an easy documentation for the fb instant games, specially at the time